# Title bar in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to edit the title bar display in Notepad++ ?

Currently I see

```
C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\lmx.txt - Notepad++
```

I would like to see just

```
lmx.txt - Notepad++
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

`Settings > Preferences... > MISC. > Show only filename in title bar.`

[image]